# Detectar si el iPhone o iPad está en modo MUTE o SILENCIO iOS Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

como puedo detectar si el dispositivo iPhone o iPad está en modo MUTE o SILENCIO ?

Necesito notificar al usuario que el dispositivo esta en modo MUTE o SILENCIO cuando reproduzco un audio .

Estoy usando AVPlayer

```
guard let url = URL.init(string: strUrl) else { return }
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)

self.player?.play()
```

Saludos.